# MongoDb C# driver projection returns name and value pair

Tags: c#, mongodb

the original data looks like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57b532aefc19a526b4cf7118"),
"_t" : [ 
    "Product", 
    "ShoppingProduct"
],
"name" : "nike jug",
"createdByUser" : "",
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-08-18T03:59:42.012Z"),
"url" : "https://localhost:44305/v1/product/1",
"description" : "a jug from nike",
"schema" : "ShoppingProduct",
"sku" : "nikejug001",
"price" : "15",
"weight" : "100",
"brand" : null,
"manufacturerId" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
"entityId" : 1,
"visibility" : 4,
"status" : 1,
"taxClassId" : 2,
"shortDescription" : "nike jug is good"
}
```

I did this

```
var result = _col.Find("{}").Project("{entityId:1}").ToList();
```

I hope the return data to be this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57b532aefc19a526b4cf7118"),
"entityId" : 1
}
```

But what I got is this:

```
{
  "name": "_id",
  "value": "57b532aefc19a526b4cf7118"
},
{
  "name": "entityId",
  "value": 1
}
```

How can I achieve something like `db.getCollection('products').find({},{entityId:1})` with C# driver?

Comment: isn't what you got the correct thing? It is the document projected to the 'entityId' only.

Comment: Hi @Newton, thanks for comment! If you look closer to the result. what I got is name and value pair for each property, while what I really what is a key value pair. say: `entityId:1` instead of `name:entityId, value:1`

Comment: could you add c# class?

Comment: @Hao any luck with this? Facing similar issue with Azure Cosmos Db. The returned values are converted to name, value pair.

Answer (score -1):

This is normal behavior. Lookup [Return the Specified Fields and the _id Field Only](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-id-field-only) vs [Return Specified Fields Only](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-specified-fields-only) in the official docs.

```
var empty = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
var docs = _col.Find(empty).Project("{_id:0, entityId:1}").ToList();
foreach (var doc in docs)
{
  if (doc.AsBsonDocument.ElementCount != 1)
    throw new Exception("Should have only entityId fields");
}
docs = _col.Find(empty).Project("{entityId:1}").ToList();
foreach (var doc in docs)
{
  if (doc.AsBsonDocument.ElementCount != 2)
    throw new Exception("Should have _id and entityId fields");
}
```